# Javascript misbehaviour on IAgree function

Tags: javascript, html, function, runtime-error

I have following code:

```
function iAgree(){
    alert("Hello");
    jQuery('#openAccount').hide();
    jQuery('#submitDetails').show();
}
```

I am calling it using:

```
<div class="openAccWraper">
  <div class="openAccDetail"> </div>
  <div class="questionContact">
    <input type="checkbox" name="iAgree" id="iAgree" value="1" />
  </div>
</div>
  <a href="#" onclick="iAgree();"><img src="img/btnSubmitDet.png" border="0" /></a>
```

I am getting following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

Comment: try change it to `$('...')..` and add `return false;` at the end of the function

Comment: Working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/WPE6n/ have you loaded jQuery in your page?

Comment: I am in doubt that iAgree keyword is somehow registered by default ?

Comment: Also I am testing it in chrome, does that matter ?

Comment: Test the fiddle it works there; I repeat have you included jQuery like: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script> in your page?

Comment: On which line does it object, on the inline handler that `iAgree` was not a function? Also show us how exactly you are including that script in the page.

Comment: @justnajm Does the alert happen or not?

Comment: No alert happens @herby, I am using the script like this <script src="../js/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>. Also I am having error with the <a tag.

Comment: Another thing I have figured out is by renaming the iAgree() to iAgree22() and it works, still unclear about the reason its not working, is it a reserve keyword ?

Comment: What other script plugin have you included in you page?

Comment: These are the liberaries and css I am using

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reveal.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="emailer.css">
<script src="../js/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery/jquery.reveal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be with the iAgree being id as well, and IIRC some (all?) browsers define the global named same as id (if it is possible as identifier). So, iAgree() tries to call DOM object, which obviously fails; and it also explains why renaming solves it.

To check if this is the case put onclick="alert(iAgree); iAgree();" and see if it alerts function or InputElement.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SZYH3/4/ checking if the dom element id interfere's with the function declaration. It identifies iAgree as a function and not a dom element.

Comment: @nimgrg This just means that in the fiddle it works. The real question is, what would the alert show at the OP's page. Things like this depend on order, structure etc.

Comment: It also means browsers don't declare dom object as global variables in js, hence having id same as a function name should not cause a conflict.

Comment: @nimgrg No it doesn't mean that, it can as well mean that iAgree function appears later than iAgree id, so it redefines it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your code is not being loaded onto the page properly. If you wrap your function code in the **head** or the **body** tag of your html, your code should work. e.g.

```
<body>
   <!-- html -->
   <!-- load your script at the bottom of the body -->
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    function iAgree(){
        alert("Hello");
        .........
     }
</script>
</body>
Or
<body>
   <!-- html -->
   <!-- load your script at the bottom of the body-->
   <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="iAgree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Here's a minimal working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SZYH3/2/.

Comment: Thanks @nimgrg but I have to complete it in my code, I appreciate your help.